# $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{2x^6+6x^3}{4x^5+3x^3}$

Tags: limits

Find $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{2x^6+6x^3}{4x^5+3x^3} .$$

The answer is $2$.  Can someone explain to me how to arrive at that?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** If $x\neq0$ then
$$\frac{2x^6+6x^3}{4x^5+3x^3}=\frac{2x^3+6}{4x^2+3}.$$